# uploading files with multer after user is authenticated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

using multer, I can successfully upload any type of file to my node.js backend from my reactjs client and I can create a user as well. Now I am trying to figure out a way to only allow authenticated users to upload files. Does anyone know of any resources that can help me figure out what I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

you can use any authentication middleware on your upload route.
for example.

```
 const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

   const authentication = function (req, res, next) {
   // handle authentication
    if(authenticated) return next()
    next({error})
   })


   app.post('/profile', authentication, upload.single('avatar'),
   function (req, res, next) {

   })
```

this will authenticate requests before multer handles the request

Comment: If I put my auth middleware before multer then I cannot access req.body
And if I put multer.single before auth then the file is uploaded before authorization

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the exact problem

Comment: I have it, too @Harry_C

Answer (score 1):

For those not getting the req.body, you can pass your tokens with the Headers like so

```
const options = {
    headers: {'jwt': sessionStorage.getItem("token")}
};
```

and for the request

```
axios.post("http://xxx", your data, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the `req.body` to authenticate the user, the bad news is that you can't. `multer` middleware is wholly responsible for parsing the request (which is of `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`), i.e. its fields and files. To access the request body, you have to wait until `multer` finishes its job, which means you have to wait until the `StorageEngine` handles all the files. This basically means **any user can upload files**, you can only authenticate the users after the upload, and if a user doesn't pass authentication, reject the request and delete the already-uploaded files.

I've written [pechkin](http://npmjs.com/package/pechkin) to solve this exact problem.

`pechkin.parseFormData()` returns a Promise that resolves when all fields are parsed, and if the first file is encountered (or when the request ends).

The promise contains a populated fields object, and a files AsyncIterator/AsyncIterable.

No need to provide storage engines, file handlers, event listeners, etc.
This means you can perform validation on the fields object, and only then have to mess with files – the files won't be parsed, processed, written to memory, saved anywhere, etc., until you decide to do so.

```js
// ESM
import { parseFormData } from 'pechkin';

// CommonJS
const { parseFormData } = require('pechkin');

// ...

app.post(
  '/upload',
  parseRequest,
  authentication,
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Process files and/or fields (`req.files`) ...
    for await (const { filename, stream, ...otherFileProps } of req.files) {
      // Process file stream...
    }
  }
);

// You can use any actual authentication middleware for Express
// that needs req.body
function authentication (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // No longer empty! Populated with all fields (see note)
  return next();
}

// A utility function to follow Express' middleware style
async function parseRequest (req, res, next) {
  const { fields, files } = await parseFormData(req, /* ...optional configs */);

  req.body = fields;
  req.files = files;

  return next();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a mongodb database to authenticate users.